# How to move AWS Elasticsearch into another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I'm moving all the instances under each service from old AWS account into new AWS account. I've found ways to move EC2 and RDS into another account.

- To move EC2 instance, I have created an AMI and shared with the new AWS account. Using that image I've created an instance
- To move RDS instance, I've created a snapshot and shared with the new AWS account. I've restored the shared snapshot in the new account

Now I need to move Elasticsearch from old account to the new one. I couldn't able to figure out a way to move my Elasticsearch. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you investigated taking a manual snapshot of ES and restoring into a new ES deployment?

Comment: @jarmod You are right? I did that and it works. I'll post the answer here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a role with Elasticsearch permission. You may also use the existing role with the following trust relationship,

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```

Provide the **iam:PassRole** for the iam user whose access/secret keys will be using to take snapshot.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:PassRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/TheServiceRole"
  }
}
```

Change the access & secret key, host, region, path, and payload in the below code and execute it.

```
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
region = 'us-west-1'
service = 'es'

awsauth = AWS4Auth(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region, service)
host = 'https://elasticsearch-domain.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/' # include https:// and trailing /

# REGISTER REPOSITORY
path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "s3-bucket-name",
    "region": "us-west-1",
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/TheServiceRole"
  }
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers) # requests.get, post, put, and delete all have similar syntax
print(r.text)
```

### To take the snapshot and store it in the S3

```
path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/my-snapshot'
url = host + path
r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth)
print(r.text)
```

Now the snapshot is ready. Share this snapshot to another account and use the same code with new account keys and endpoint to restore it using the below code snippet.

### To restore all indices from the snapshot

```
path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/my-snapshot/_restore'
url = host + path
r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth)
print(r.text)
```

### To restore single index from the snapshot

```
path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/my-snapshot/_restore'
url = host + path
payload = {"indices": "my-index"}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

Reference: [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html).